# How to debug/log useful information inside immer callback?

Tags: reactjs, immer.js

I'm using [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) in a react app to handle state changes. Let's say the state didn't change as I expected, so I'd want to debug it, but both `console.log` and `debugger` gives a `Proxy` object which doesn't contain any useful information, e.g. what is the state at that time.

Example code to get the new state:

```
return immer(state, draftState => {
    // Some mutations here, didn't go as expected
    console.log(draftState.blah) // Gives 'Proxy' object
    debugger // Same deal
  })
```

How can I debug my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out you just need to dig in in chrome dev tools - e.g. if you are using the debugger, then on the right-side panel you can click into `Scope -> Local -> searchTarget -> [[Target]] -> base/draft`, where you can see the actual values.

Comment: The current version of Immer puts the actual value under the `[[Target]] -> t ` property (I'm not sure where you see base/draft). Either way, thanks! I never saw that before.

Comment: If you want to inspect the object further in the console, you can right click on the value and say 'Store as global' which will give you `temp1` you can then use in the console

Answer (score 32):

Immer 7+ has `current()` for this purpose. So, you can do this:

```
import { current } from 'immer';

console.log(current(draft));
```

Official [documentation](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/current) and [test](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/31684f262a9ec16d5aadb82156a78e81b98f65ef/__tests__/current.js#L40)

Comment: Yes but you cannot do that using a breakpoint based debugger, that's equivalent to using a console.log

Comment: @EricBurel Why not? Add breakpoint and then add a watcher to check the value.    
  
You need to check how immer module is imported and under what name it is available in the current context and then you can create the watcher.
For example in create-react-app type of project watcher would look similar to this:
`immer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.current(draft)`

Comment: I did not know about watcher, I'll dig that, thank you!

Answer (score 23):

If you serialize / de-serialize the draft, the output will be a plain JavaScript object and will appear as such in the console.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(draft)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: How did you find this? It only says "proxy" on the console. I wonder how it internally works, can you elobarate?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that is coming across this and is confused as to how to find the `Scope -> Local -> searchTarget -> [[Target]] -> base/draft` make sure that you set the `debugger`. Once that's set, you'll see the right-side panel of the `Sources` tab with the relevant info:

[image]